# How to consume ManagedServiceFactory services

Tags: java, osgi

I have a class that implements `ManagedServiceFactory` like this:

```
public class GreeterFactory implements ManagedServiceFactory {
    private volatile BundleContext bundleContext =
            FrameworkUtil.getBundle(GreeterFactory.class).getBundleContext();
    private final Map<String, ServiceRegistration> registrations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Greeter Factory Implementation";
    }

    /**
     * Greeter Service Factory
     * @param pid this is the PID of the Configuration received.
     * @param dictionary the Configuration to prepare the service.
     * @throws ConfigurationException
     */
    @Override
    public void updated(String pid, Dictionary<String, ?> dictionary) throws ConfigurationException {
        String message = (String) dictionary.get("message");
        if (message == null) {
            throw new ConfigurationException("message",
                                                    "Required property 'message' missing");
        }
        GreeterService greeter;
        synchronized (registrations) {
            if (registrations.containsKey(pid)) {
                greeter = (GreeterService) bundleContext.getService(registrations.get(pid).getReference());
            } else {
                // For each new configuration, the factory register a new service with
                // the given properties/configuration
                greeter = new GreeterImpl();

                ServiceRegistration greeterRegistration =
                        bundleContext.registerService(GreeterService.class.getName(),
                                                                           greeter,
                                                                           dictionary);

                System.out.print("\nRegistering Config-PID: " + pid + "\n");
                registrations.put(pid, greeterRegistration);
            }
        }

        greeter.setMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleted(String pid) {
        ServiceRegistration component = null;
        synchronized (registrations) {
            component = registrations.remove(pid);
        }
        // Calling services from a synchronized block can lead to deadlocks,
        // so Dependency Manager must be called outside.
        if(component != null) {
            bundleContext.ungetService(component.getReference());
        }
    }
}
```

The factory works OK. I also have a test case to consume the services created for each configuration sent by the `ConfigurationAdmin` service, here is the test case:

```
Configuration configuration1 = configurationAdmin.createFactoryConfiguration("example.factoryservice.greeter", null);

Dictionary properties = new Properties();
properties.put("message", "Hello factory world 1!");
configuration1.update(properties);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

Configuration configuration2 = configurationAdmin.createFactoryConfiguration("example.factoryservice.greeter", null);

properties = new Properties();
properties.put("message", "Hello factory world 2!");
configuration2.update(properties);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

ServiceReference<GreeterService> sRef = context.getServiceReference(GreeterService.class);
GreeterService greeterService = context.getService(sRef);

assertEquals("Hello factory world 1!", greeterService.sayHello());

greeterService = context.getService(sRef);

assertEquals("Hello factory world 2!", greeterService.sayHello()); // FAILS!!
```

Now, I am kind of lost here and I cannot find any documentation about this part, but how do I determine in code what `Greeter` service to use depending on the configuration I need?

I created in code 2 `Greeter` configurations, the factory then registered a couple of `Greeter` services, each with a different configuration, how I decide in code an instance of a `Greeter` service with Configuration 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ManagedServiceFactory is pretty low level. Unless you want to implement a technology, you do not need it. In case you want to implement business logic, use one of the [Component Models](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Component_Models_Overview).

But, to answer your specific question:

You register the GreeterService with the service properties that you get from the configuration. That means that you can filter on these services.

Note, that *BundleContext* has a function where you can pass OSGi service filter as well. E.g.:

```
Collection<ServiceReference<GreeterService>> sRefs = 
    context.getServiceReferences(GreeterService.class,
                                 "(message=Hello factory world 2!)");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes I am actually using a service filter to get the one I need. Even though, I finally added a property `type` with value `<configuration1.getPid()>` and filtered the service with `(type=configuration1.getPid())` this way the service is directly bound to the configuration PID.